# How does Ubuntu One sync two machines with identical file content?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I have a notebook and a desktop computer, both running Ubuntu 11.10. I used to sync between the two with the help of Unison, so both computers have identical content in the Documents folder.

I decided to try UbuntuOne. My question is, if I activate UbuntuOne for the two machines for the folders with identical contents, will UbuntuOne be able to recognise that, or will it sync to the cloud everything twice (and then down on the other machine).

To put it another way, will I end up having two copies of everything on the machines and on the cloud, and therefore should delete the identical files on one of the machines before activating UbuntuOne, or not.

Thank you, and if there *is* already something on the net about this, I'd be glad if somebody posted the link here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect the first computer. It will sync with the cloud. Wait until it finishes, and then connect the other computer. It will recognize the files and not upload anything, but from them on, if you add, remove or change a file from one, the same will happen with the other.